# How to store JSONObject from url in SharedPreferences

Tags: java, json, url, sharedpreferences

I have parsed and fetched data from a JSON Url. The data is about the amount of rain for the coming five days. I want to store the data in SharedPreferences so the coming five days will become the past five days and the JSON Url will deliver new data for the coming five days. So I want a SharedPreferences with 10 values that can remove data older than 10 days and eventually this data will be shown into a graph.

I have tried to figure out how to store a JSONObject in SharedPreferences, but haven't had any luck so far. I am pretty new to Java and coding in general, so I would love your help. I have two activities. The MainActivity and the fetchData activity were the parsing and fetching from the JSON Url happends. How should I add the SharedPreferences to this code?

MainActivity

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ImageButton adviser;
    private ImageButton location;
    Button click;
    public static TextView data;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        click = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        adviser = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imagebutton);
        location= (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButtonLocation);
        data = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.fetcheddata);



        click.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                fetchData process = new fetchData();
                process.execute();

            }
        });
```

fetchData Activity

```
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class fetchData extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {
    String data = "";
    private TextView setText;


    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        StringBuilder builder = null;

        try {
            URL url = new URL("https://data.buienradar.nl/2.0/feed/json");
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            String line = "";
            builder = new StringBuilder();
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                builder.append(line);
                data = data + line;

            }

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);

        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();


        try {
            JSONObject jsonData = new JSONObject(data);
            JSONObject forecast = jsonData.getJSONObject("forecast");
            //JSONObject fivedayforecast = forecast.getJSONObject("fivedayforecast");
            JSONArray fivedayforecast = forecast.getJSONArray("fivedayforecast");

            for (int i = 0; i < fivedayforecast.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject object = fivedayforecast.getJSONObject(i);
                //mmRainMin[i] = Integer.parseInt(object.getString("mmRainMin"));
                String datum = object.getString("day");
                String mmRainMin = object.getString("mmRainMin"); //opslaan in shared preferences, makkelijk parameter maken of locale file met max 10 waarden

                stringBuilder.append("The amount of rain on " + datum + " is " + mmRainMin + " mm" + "\n");
                MainActivity.data.setText(stringBuilder.toString()); //changed textView to data, data.setText(stringBuilder.toString());

                Log.e("mmRainMin", mmRainMin);


            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            //Log.e("", e.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You could save the whole JSON respond into a string into SharePreference. And next time during read turn it back from string into json object.
Sharepreference don't do well storing nested object. You could consider saving it into a file in internal storage as well.

Comment: Thanks Babyish Tank. So where exactly should I put the SharePreference? After catch, or should I create a new class?